# copying a DataGridView from one form to another

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am making a form for a supermarket purchase, each item added to cart is shown in a datagridview in the same form[first form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPOHA.png) once purchase is done a new form is open where I want the datagridview from the first form to be shown.
I saw some solutions and tried the next code in my first form:

```
this.Hide();
Form frm35 = new Form35(dataGridView1.DataSource);
frm35.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

and in the second:

```
 public partial class Form35 : Form
{
    public Form35(object dataSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;

       
    }

    private void Form35_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        
    }
  
}
```

however, the datagridview in the second form(form 35) is still empty.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code will work fine if you open the second form after first form grid bind to datasource. 
Check the below code for ref:

**form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Step 3: here we add 5 rows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form frm35 = new Form2(dataGridView1.DataSource);
        frm35.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

**Form2.cs**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(object dataSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Thanks,